# LINQ left join with group by and correct count

Tags: c#, linq

Exist there and alternative way to count this?

```
IList<DtoProfile> profileList = Session().QueryOver<DtoProfile>()
IList<Headword> methodList = Session().QueryOver<Headword>()
var hList = profileList.Select(x => x.HeadwordList).SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
```

profileList contains a HeadwordList. Now hList contains Headwords like

> Headword1: ID = 1, Text = Text1 (from Profile 1)
>   Headword2: ID = 2, Text = Text2 (from Profile 1)
>   Headword1: ID = 1, Text = Text1 (from
>   Profile 2)

methodList contains

> Headword1: ID = 1, Text = Text1
>   Headword2: ID = 2, Text = Text2
>   Headword2: ID = 3, Text = Text3

I want to make a Dictionary like

> Key: Text1, Value: 2
>   Key: Text2, Value: 1
>   Key: Text3, Value: 0

```
var joined = (from headword in methodList
   join profile in hList on headword equals profile
   group headword by headword.Text
   into groupedProfile
   select groupedProfile).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());
```

It not works! I got just

> Key: Text1, Value: 2
>   Key: Text2, Value: 1
>   in my Dictionary.
>   Now i improved to with left join:

```
var joined = (from headword in methodList
   join profile in hList on headword equals profile into ps
   from profile in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
   group headword by headword.Text
   into groupedProfile
   select groupedProfile).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count(y => y != null));
```

But y => y != null not works correctly!
I get:

> Key: Text1, Value: 2
>    Key: Text2, Value: 1
>   Key: Text3, Value: 1 (wrong, should be 0)

Comment: Are those `QueryOver` methods actually returning lists? You could optimize it better if you left it as `IQueryable` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really sure if I understood your problem, but maybe...

```
var joined = methodList
    .ToDictionary(item => item.Text, item => hList.Count(h => h.Text == item.Text))
```